# Ubuntu 18.04: Wireless broken after updating to kernel-hwe-5.0.0.23

Tags: boot, networking, 18.04, wireless, kernel

Recently my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS system was updated to kernel-hwe-5.0.0.23.

I need to use kernel-hwe for my HP 14-cm0202ng notebook because the wireless driver in kernel 4.15 is not up-to-date.

The driver from github break after switching on/off wireless (usually when doing suspend, i.e. closing the lid).

The wireless driver from 5.0.0.23 is not working at all. Consequently I do not get any internet connection.

Also very often the notebook hangs up during boot (after grub) on 5.0.0.23. This also happens with 4.15 but not with 4.18.

I tried to uninstall 5.0.0.23 however this breaks dependencies (i.e. hwe updates no more available).

Any suggestions what to do except changing kernel boot sequence with a tool like grub-customizer ?